# How to set android reminder/alarm?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have got some times stored in ISO format. Some of these times are flagged to either 1(on) or 0(off) set in another column. I need to set  a reminder at the times flagged to 1, but how would I pass that each date to the reminder class?

Comment: What "reminder class"? There is no Reminder class in the Android SDK.

Comment: Is there anyway that i could set reminders then?

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for the Alarm Clock application.

There is no public API for the Calendar application, though since it is a native UI for a Google Calendar, you could push an event over to the Google Calendar via its GData API.

Comment: Hmm that seems a bit complicated, there must be a way to set an alarm from these times or even just a toast message at one of the times.

Comment: Well, you can certainly implement something yourself using `AlarmManager`. However, that requires you to handle it all yourself. Please remember that your original question assumed the existence of a "reminder class", so I have been assuming that doing it yourself was not something you were interested in.

Comment: Sorry i didnt make myself clear , i should of said that i would write an alarm/reminder class. It seems easy enough to write a notification/alarm class but just seems difficult to pass the time from the db to the alarm manager class .

Comment: So long as you can parse the ISO time, it should not be that big of a deal. You might consider opening a new question (or editing this one) with more details about specifically where you are having problems in using `AlarmManager` with your database contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentValues reminderContentValues = new ContentValues();
reminderContentValues.put(FIELD_REMINDER_EVENT_ID, eventId);    
reminderContentValues.put(FIELD_REMINDER_METHOD, 1);    
reminderContentValues.put(FIELD_REMINDER_MIN, minutesBefore);   
mContext.getContentResolver().insert(getRemindersUri(), reminderContentValues);
```